# PhotoFilmStrip bug

Tags: software-installation, codecs, slideshow

I finally managed to install PhotoFilmStrip on my Ubuntu 16.04.
The latest version I found was photofilmstrip_2.1.0-1_all.deb.
Although I had to install manually some dependencies, it looked like I managed to install it correctly.

However, if I try to create a project limited to a total length (either user defined or loading some audio file), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/gui/DlgProjectProps.py", line 342, in OnCmdBrowseAudioButton
    self.__LoadAudioFile(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/gui/DlgProjectProps.py", line 399, in __LoadAudioFile
    mediaCtrl = AudioPlayer(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/core/GPlayer.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.__Identify()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/core/GPlayer.py", line 47, in __Identify
    d = gst.parse_launch("filesrc name=source ! decodebin2 ! fakesink")
GError: no element "decodebin2"
```

I finally gave up and tried to create a project without any time restriction. However, when I tried to render it, in the ***Format*** drop-down there is no selectable option - all of them appear in gray with a no-entry sign.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall it several times, still get the same problem.

================= UPDATE =====================

I found photofilmstrip_3.0.0-1_all.deb on this url:
https://es.osdn.net/projects/sfnet_photostoryx/downloads/photofilmstrip/2.9.95/photofilmstrip_3.0.0-1_all.deb/

While installing it (`sudo dpkg -i photofilmstrip_3.0.0-1_all.deb`) I got:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of photofilmstrip:
 photofilmstrip depends on python-gst-1.0; however:
  Package python-gst-1.0 is not installed.
    :
    :
Errors were encountered while processing:
 photofilmstrip
```

So I ran `sudo apt-get install python-gst-1.0` and then installed it again, and that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try version 3.0 from the 2.9.95 download section here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/photostoryx

After downloading do :

```
sudo dpkg -i photofilmstrip_3.0.0-1_all.deb

sudo apt-get -f install
```

And then run photofilmstrip and try it.

Comment: I can download from this url only photofilmstrip_2.1.0-1_all.deb. I couldn't find any higher version.

Answer (score 1):

You can install PhotoFilmStrip in just three steps:

1. Visit [this link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/photostoryx) to download the installation package.
2. Open the downloaded package with Ubuntu Software.
3. Click the *Install* button and enter the sudo password.